# Python Selenium Locate Element within P tags by XPATH

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

On the following website (https://play2048.co/) is a game called 2048. After I use Selenium to play it eventually gets to a point where is says Game Over!

When I inspect the element (see picture) I see the word Game Over! in p tags. I wish to be able to capture this text and store it in a Python variable as below:

```
TextV = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/p'))).text
```

I got the XPath by simply right clicking the text in the p tags (inspect element) and selected copy full XPath but it seems Selenium cannot find this text element when I run the whole code.

[image]

Thannks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use CSS_Selector, because it tends to be more correct, and it's more likely to be successful.

So i would recommend something along the lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Your Code Here

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'the css selector'))).text
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to try the code (GameOver = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.game-message.game-over'))).text) in Python interpreter and it works!